# A solution for multilingual websites having a different domain name for each language

Tags: joomla-4.x, multilingual, multi-sites

I was looking for an easy to implement solution for multilingual websites having a different domain name for each language... for Joomla 4.

In Joomla 3 there were a couple of plugins, but there is nothing atm for Joomla 4.
So I have worked on that and found a solution which I describe in detail here:
https://github.com/woluweb/a_different_domain_name_for_each_language

The only thing that my .htaccess does not do (but that the Language2Domain plugin for J3 does for example) is to remove the language tag (/en/, /nl/, ...) after the correct domain name.

Probably the redirections in .htaccess can be adapted to manage that?
Or maybe it requires to change something to the `System - Language Filter` plugin?
If you have any view on that, feel free to shoot :)

My goal is to write an article explaining this solution for the September edition of the Joomla Community Magazine.
So any input/feedback/suggestion/comment/... will help! :)

Txs,

Marc